# regex to check the string in text box

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I have a text input field and I want to check what users put in there. I want to allow them to put a monetary amount with or with out $. They should be able to enter:

```
$12
$12.0
12
12.0
$ 12.0
```

not sure how would I do that. I think regex may help, but I'm not sure how to do that.

Comment: How is this related to the jquery-ui tag? Maybe you meant jquery-validate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basic regular expression.

```
(/^\$?\s?\d+(\.\d+)?$/).test("$12.0");


/ -Beginning of Reg Exp
^ - Start of line
\$? - Match a $ or not
\s? - Match a space or not
\d+ - match one or more numbers
(\.\d+)? - match a decimal point followed by more numbers
$ - match end of a line
/ - end of reg expression
```

This will fail

`12.` and `.0`

since they were not in your possible solutions

Comment: If you want to allow `12.` and `.10`, see my answer to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12724801/contains-only-digit-and-comma-or-dot-in-c-sharp/12724908#12724908). But if it's money, shouldn't you require EXACTLY 2 digits after the decimal?